# How to view altair chart on non-notebook environment

Tags: altair

I have created a program by using altair library in .py file not in notebook.
In this program the plot is plotted by using iris dataset between sepalWidth and petalWidth with the regression line code is right but as I have created this in python file so after running the code in the terminal it throws the NotImplementedError.
My question is how to view the altair chart if I'm writing the program in python file.
I read out the documentation but didn't understand which renderer I have to enbale.
[This is the error which I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjzfa.png)

Comment: Please paste your error in the question.

Answer (score 1):

See [Working in non-notebook environments](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/display_frontends.html#working-in-non-notebook-environments) in Altair's documentation for information on displaying charts in non-notebook environments. If you have specific issues with any of those approaches, please edit your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue you're seeing.